# Sqoop import all tables not syncing with Hive database

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I imported MySQL database tables to Hive using sqoop tool by using below script.

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username=retail_dba --password=cloudera --hive-import --hive-overwrite --create-hive-table --warehouse-dir=/user/hive/warehouse/
```

but when I check the database in hive, there is no retail.db.

Comment: Add --verbose flag and check sqoop logs

Comment: check in `default` database. Are you seeing all you tables from retail_db database ?

Comment: @devツ yes iam able to see

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import all tables in a specific hive database *(already created)*. Use:

`--hive-database retail`

in your sqoop command.

Answer (score 0):

as dev said if you want to sqoop everything in a particular db then use

--hive-database retail_db else every tables will be sqooped under default warehouse dir/tablename

Answer (score -1):

Your command sqoops everything into this directory: `/user/hive/warehouse/retail.db/`

To import into hive use this argument: `--hive-import` and why are you using `--as-textfile`?

If you want to store as textfile then use `--as-textfile` and then use hive external table command to create external tables in Hive.

Comment: its importing all tables but which i switch back to hive to verify, shows not database